# <p:confirm> internationalization jsf

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I just ran into some weirdo thing in  internationalization. In fact, I have some portion of a jsf page that looks like this

```
<p:commandButton title="#{msg['delete']}" icon="ui-icon-trash" update="form"
                 actionListener="#{homePageController.delete}">
    <p:confirm header="#{msg['confirmation']}" message="#{msg['are.you.sure']} ?" 
               icon="ui-icon-alert" />  
</p:commandButton>

<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="drop">  
        <p:commandButton value="#{msg['yes']}" type="button" 
                         styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" 
                         icon="ui-icon-check"/>  
        <p:commandButton value="#{msg['no']}" type="button" 
                         styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" 
                         icon="ui-icon-close"/>       
</p:confirmDialog>
```

And the problem that appears is that, whenever I switch language, all the String are translated except the **header** and the **message** of **p:confirm**.

Note also that i use ajax request and that if I refresh the page, everything works fine.

Here are some snapshot with the problems highlighted (I've not yet translate in french)
[image] [image]

And if I refresh the page, I got what I want
[image]

Comment: make sure you `update` them when you change language/ or do a try a full page reload

Comment: I'm sure that the update work well since yes, no and also the toolbar actions titles are well translated. Also, the full page reload save my problem (I've also mentionned that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. It's probably a bug with Primefaces. I just got rid of **p:confirm** :

```
<p:commandButton title="#{msg['delete']}" icon="ui-icon-trash" type="button"
                 onclick="confirmation.show()" />

<p:confirmDialog widgetVar="confirmation" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="drop"
                 header="#{msg['confirmation']}" 
                 message="#{msg['are.you.sure']} ?">

        <p:commandButton value="#{msg['yes']}" icon="ui-icon-check"
                         styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" update="form" 
                         actionListener="#{homePageController.delete}"
                         oncomplete="confirmation.hide()"/>

        <p:commandButton value="#{msg['no']}" type="button" 
                         styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no"
                         icon="ui-icon-close" onclick="confirmation.hide()"/>

</p:confirmDialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also just ran into same problem. Manual page refresh solves my problem(I don't know if you meant on manual page refresh).

Than I added this to my commandLink that changes locale and it works:

```
oncomplete="javascript:location.reload(true)"
```